# How of fix "'gbk' codec can't decode byte" error in python pdb tool?

Tags: python, debugging, unicode, pdb

There are some Chinese comments in my code. The pdb debugger will raise a UnicodeDecodeError only when some specific characters appear.

Here's the source file `util.py`:

```py
"""代码清单 util.py"""
import json

def load_info(path):
    """读取json文件"""
    with open(path) as f:
        return json.load(f)

def print_info(info):
    """打印信息"""
    for k, v in info.items():
        print('{}: {}'.format(k, v))

def to_upper(info):
    """将键值中的字符串转为大写"""
    for k, v in info.items():
        if isinstance(v, str):
            info[k] = v.upper()
    return info
```

And here's the error message when I try to add a break point:

```
E:\10-写作\01-技术\01-Python\Python代码调试全面介绍\src
λ python -m pdb util.py
> e:\10-写作\01-技术\01-python\python代码调试全面介绍\src\util.py(1)<module>()
-> """代码清单 util.py"""
(Pdb) b print_info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python37\lib\pdb.py", line 648, in do_break
    lineno = int(arg)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'print_info'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python37\lib\pdb.py", line 659, in do_break
    code = func.__code__
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__code__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python37\lib\pdb.py", line 1701, in main
    pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\pdb.py", line 1570, in _runscript
    self.run(statement)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\bdb.py", line 585, in run
    exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "e:\10-写作\01-技术\01-python\python代码调试全面介绍\src\util.py", line 1, in <module>
    """代码清单 util.py"""
  File "e:\10-写作\01-技术\01-python\python代码调试全面介绍\src\util.py", line 1, in <module>
    """代码清单 util.py"""
  File "D:\Python37\lib\bdb.py", line 88, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\bdb.py", line 112, in dispatch_line
    self.user_line(frame)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\pdb.py", line 261, in user_line
    self.interaction(frame, None)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\pdb.py", line 352, in interaction
    self._cmdloop()
  File "D:\Python37\lib\pdb.py", line 321, in _cmdloop
    self.cmdloop()
  File "D:\Python37\lib\cmd.py", line 138, in cmdloop
    stop = self.onecmd(line)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\pdb.py", line 418, in onecmd
    return cmd.Cmd.onecmd(self, line)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\cmd.py", line 217, in onecmd
    return func(arg)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\pdb.py", line 667, in do_break
    (ok, filename, ln) = self.lineinfo(arg)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\pdb.py", line 740, in lineinfo
    answer = find_function(item, fname)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\pdb.py", line 100, in find_function
    for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xac in position 329: illegal multibyte sequence
Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging
Running 'cont' or 'step' will restart the program
> d:\python37\lib\pdb.py(100)find_function()
-> for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
(Pdb)
```

But when after I remove some Chinese characters, there won't be any errors. I removed some comments for `to_upper` function:

```py
def to_upper(info):
    """将键值中"""
    for k, v in info.items():
        if isinstance(v, str):
            info[k] = v.upper()
    return info
```

Then the error just is gone:

```
(Pdb) b print_info
Breakpoint 2 at e:\10-写作\01-技术\01-python\python代码调试全面介绍\src\util.py:11
```

The source file is encoded in UTF-8 format. I don't know what's going on here.